# How to add columns to all dataframes in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes, for each of which I want to calculate the length of certain columns' string values, and create a new column with those calculated values:

```
columns = ['name', 'address', 'email']
newcolumns = ['name_length', 'address_length', 'email_length']
```

Code:

```
def length(start, i, j):
    while i < len(columns):
        newcol = newcolumns[i]
        col = columns[j]
        df_list[start][newcol] = df_list[start][col].str.len()
        i += 1
        j += 1
    start += 1
    return df_list
```

each individual dataframe can be accessed like a list, ie `df[0]`.

The result I got only calculated the first dataframe's name- and address- length. The rest of the dataframes didn't get calculated.

**The expected result is all specified columns in all dataframes got calculated results.** The ideal answer will achieve this by automating it with loops, lambda.

How can I revise my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to update each dataframe in `df_list`, it must properly indexed so the new columns can be assigned to the correct dataframe in the `list`, which is accomplished by using `enumerate`.
- Of the 3 options shown, `.applymap(len)` is the fastest option for a dataframe of 100k rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
data = {'test': range(3), 'name': ['a', 'bc', 'def'], 'address': ['add1', 'add11', 'add111'],
        'email': ['i_am_lame_4_not_providing_my_own_sample_dataframe@lameduck.com', 'xyz@lameduck.com', 'wxyz@lamerduck.com']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_list = [df1, df2]

columns = ['name', 'address', 'email']
newcolumns = ['name_length', 'address_length', 'email_length']

# iterate through list of dataframes and add _length columns
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    
    # create the new columns and assign them to the correct dataframe in the list
    df_list[i][newcolumns] = df[columns].applymap(len)

# display(df1)
   test name address                                                           email  name_length  address_length  email_length
0     0    a    add1  i_am_lame_4_not_providing_my_own_sample_dataframe@lameduck.com            1               4            62
1     1   bc   add11                                                xyz@lameduck.com            2               5            16
2     2  def  add111                                              wxyz@lamerduck.com            3               6            18
```

- Technically, this can be accomplished without using `enumerate` to index each dataframe in the list.

  - This works for `lists` of dataframes because `df` is a reference, so when it's updated in the loop, the proper dataframe in the `list` is updated.
  - I think it's less evident what is happening, which is why I show the code using `enumerate`.

```py
for df in df_list:
    df[newcolumns] = df[columns].applymap(len)
```

### Alternatives

#### Alternative 1

```py
# zip the columns and new column name together
cols = list(zip(columns, newcolumns))

# iterate through list of dataframe
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):

    # iterate through the column name pairs
    for c in cols:

        # create the columns using .str.len()
        df_list[i][c[1]] = df[c[0]].str.len()
```

#### Alternative 2

```py
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i][newcolumns] = df[columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.len())
```

### `%%timeit` tests

```py
# sample dataframe with 99999 rows
d = pd.concat([df1]* 33333).reset_index(drop=True)

# functions to test
columns = ['name', 'address', 'email']
newcolumns = ['name_length', 'address_length', 'email_length']
cols = list(zip(columns, newcolumns))

def test1(df):
    df[newcolumns] = df[columns].applymap(len)
    return df


def test2(df):
    for c in cols:
        df[c[1]] = df[c[0]].str.len()
    return df
    

def test3(df):
    df[newcolumns] = df[columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.len())
    return df


# tests
%%timeit
test1(d)
[out]:
67.6 ms ± 1.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
test2(d)
[out]:
87.6 ms ± 2.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
test3(d)
[out]:
89.4 ms ± 543 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```